# How to include a JavaScript file in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: javascript, cakephp, include

I am trying to include a .js file I created by using this:

```
echo $this->Html->script('vote');
```

My file is in /js/vote.js

I load the website and I go to the sourcecode, I click on the .js script file to see what it is loading and what I find out is that that the is an error loading vote.js

When I try to access directly from the URL using:

http://localhost:8888/mysite/js/vote.js

I find this:

---

```
Error: JsController could not be found.
Error: Create the class JsController below in file: app/Controller/JsController.php

<?php

class JsController extends AppController {

}
```

---

Then I created what it says, I get another error:

---

```
Missing Method in JsController

Error: The action vote.js is not defined in controller JsController

Error: Create JsController::vote.js() in file: app/Controller/JsController.php.

<?php

class JsController extends AppController {

    public function vote.js() {

    }

}
```

---

What's the problem?  Why is it so complicate to load a .JS file?

I am just trying to make a button to vote on articles and I am driven crazy...

Comment: It definately shouldn't be a difficult task.  There must be some form of glaring error (ie missing a js file...etc) or something wrong in the CakePHP setup like rewrite not working, or file structure off...etc

Comment: Rewrite is working in the page. But it seems like it doesn't allow me to see the .js file if there is not a view created for it. (as it happend with other actions)

I don't get why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you created a file called "vote.js" in your app/webroot/js folder?

Comment: Ok, that's it. Thanks!!
By the way. Why it takes it from webroot?? Should i put there all my css and js files?

Why doesn't it take it from js folder, or lib..

Answer (score 0):

you include it correctly!

my guess: mod_rewrite not on or some other wrong config setting

Comment: Finally i get it worked. I had to place it on webroot. Thanks anyway.